# Remain logged in to SMTP server while sending out emails

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have a website where I give the opportunity to users to subscribe to a newsletter.

Once a user inputs their email, I want to send them a confirmation email which contains a link with a token. As usual, once the user clicks the link, their email is confirmed and added to my subscribers' database.

I have successfully implemented this with PHPMailer using the following steps:

1. Create an email account on my host ( for example, the address noreply@myhost.com )
2. On my PHP code, when I want to send an email from that email addres, do an SMTP login using 'localhost' as domain name and as username and password the ones I used on the email account creation on step 1.
3. Send the email.

When the user clicks the 'Subscribe to our newsletter' button, he sees a loading icon and gets a message telling him to check his inbox. Step 2 (the SMTP login) takes the most time to execute from PHP.

Is there any way to remain logged in the SMTP account and just send out emails when users request to subscribe to the newsletter so as to reduce the loading time (and possibly the server load)?

Comment: PHP is not persistent. When an http request is completed, PHP shuts down. There'd be nothing running on the server to keep that smtp connection open. And each PHP instance would need its own smtp connection anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're overkilling. No need for logging in each time. All you need for sending email using PHPMailer is

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';


if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: No I am not overkilling in any way. If I don't login through SMTP then the from is `somethingelse@somedomain.com` (the domain of my webspace) and the reply-to is the one I set to the From address (`noreply@mydomain.com`)